# Why does NAD+ become reduced if it gains a hydrogen proton?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, cellular-respiration

I've heard that $\ce{NAD^+}$ gains a Hydrogen proton during glycolysis and the Krebs cycle and becomes reduced to $\ce{NADH}$. However, isn't reduction when a molecule receives an electron?

Maybe I've been misinformed? Does $\ce{NADH}$ gain a Hydrogen electron, not a proton?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct that reduction is simply a gain of electrons. This results in a decrease in oxidation number.

You know that NAD<sup>+</sup> is reduced by this process because it starts off with a positive charge (+1) and ends up with a neutral charge (0).

The [reducing agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reducing_agent) that is donating the electrons is the hydrogen. More correctly, the electrons come from the [hydride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydride) (H<sup>-</sup>).

The hydride is represented by 2 electrons on this redox diagram:
[image]

As you can see, the reduction reaction transfers a proton (H<sup>+</sup>) and hydride electrons (H<sup>-</sup> or 2e<sup>-</sup>) to NAD<sup>+</sup>. One electron goes to the nitrogen, and the other to the carbon where the proton binds. More details on the redox reaction of NAD can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotinamide_adenine_dinucleotide#Physical_and_chemical_properties).

Comment: Hydride anions do not exist in biochemical reactions.